# Is the set of piecewise monotonic functions on $[a,b]$ a vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, monotone-functions

I'm interested in the following question:

> Is the set of piecewise monotonic functions on $[a,b]$ a vector space?

I believe the answer is no, and here is my proposed counterexample:

Consider the interval $I=[0,1]$, and let 
$$ \begin{align}
f(x)&=2x+\int_0^xt \sin \left( \frac{1}{t} \right) \mathrm{d} t \\
g(x)&=2x
\end{align}$$
It's easy to see that both $f,g$ are monotonically increasing in $I$. Their difference however, has derivative
$$x \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right), $$
which changes its sign infinitely many times in $I$.

Is this a valid counterexample? Thanks.

Comment: I think that it is OK.

Comment: I think as well that your argument is valid.

Comment: It doesn't form a vector space, however, the space of all _differences_ of such functions does form a vector space, which if you mod out by constants is isometric to the space of all finite signed measures on $[a,b]$ when completed with the TV norm.

Comment: @Shalop The space can also be described as functions with bounded variation, am I right?

Comment: @Adayah Yes because any BV function is the difference of two increasing functions (so you dont even need the completion I mentioned before).